# Swift Generics: Constraining Argument Types

Tags: swift, generics

Coming from a C++ background (templates), I'm struggling to understand why the following piece of Swift code (generics) does not compile:

```
func backwards<T>(array: [T]) -> [T] {
    let reversedCollection = array.sort(>)

    return reversedCollection
}
```

The way I understand it is that `T` is a generic type on which I do not put any constraint (`<T>`) and declare `array` to be of type `Array<T>`. Yet this produces the following error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'sort()'

I understand that constraints can be put on the generic type using protocols. However, in this case, I don't want any constraint on `T`. Rather, I want to constrain the type of the first parameter.

I've been reading Apple's documentation on Generic Types for a few hours now but I'm still not much wiser. I have the impression that this is not possible and constraints are put solely on the declared types, but that's as far as I got.

**So the question is**: If possible, how do I put constraints on the types of the function arguments? If not, how do I achieve the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort(>)` is legal only when `Element` is `Comparable`. Since the element type of `[T]` is `T`, `T` must conform to `Comparable` in order for the array `[T]` to be sortable via `>`:

```
func backwards<T: Comparable>(array: [T]) -> [T] {
    let reversedCollection = array.sort(>)

    return reversedCollection
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work indeed. Unfortunately, I didn't deduce that from the compiler message. I would have expected some error message involving T and a comparison operator. For future debugging reference, could you clarify this a bit more?

Comment: @OnMyLittleDuck Actually, this is poor erring on the compiler's part. I suggest that you file a bug report at https://bugs.swift.org.